# read on inotify descriptor is blocked forever

Tags: c++, c, inotify, file-monitoring

My program uses [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify%20inotify) for monitoring changes on files.
My code is as following:

```
    fd = inotify_init();
    wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, "./test.txt", IN_ALL_EVENTS);
    len = read(fd, buff, BUFF_SIZE);
    while (i < len) {
        struct inotify_event *pevent = (struct inotify_event *) &buff[i];
                //process events
        i += sizeof(struct inotify_event) + pevent->len;
    }
```

However, after I got several events for the first change in the monitored files (event `IN_OPEN`, `IN_MODIFY`, `IN_ACESS`, etc.), later changes in the monitored files does generate any other events ==> my program hang out at the read function (the read is blocked)

Could you guys help me explain this error.

Answer (score 0):

please show what operations actually happen to "./test.txt" and more about your code (buff, BUFF_SIZE). And here is some point for you to check:

- There are some special events like IN_IGNORED which may remove watch from the file
- I suggest to use select/poll/epoll to monitor the fd rather than BLOCKING read on it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It help me a lot. I just want to ask you another question. Why when I open file using Vim or Gedit, I always got the event IN_DELETE_ITSELF?

Comment: @khanhhh89 i believe that you have edited "test.txt" and save it. My vim is 7.3 and i find that it actually use `open("test.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0664)` and write contents to it. So i believe that **IN_DELETE_ITSELF** is caused by O_TRUNC.

Comment: @wgwang So it's the reason why after I read first events, using inotify_add_watch("test.txt") again will results in error "No such file or directory"???

Comment: what operations actually happened on `test.txt`? i try `inotify` with vim open, save but there is no `IN_DELETE_ITSELF` or `IN_IGNORED `

Comment: @khanhhh89 i tried another version: vim 7.0 and yes i got your result. Actually, when u edit `test.txt`, vim 7.0 will first `rename("test.txt", "test.txt~")`, then write your editing content to `test.txt` and finally `unlink("test.txt~")`. So you see that the original `test.txt` is actually deleted, and inotify get the event of `IN_DELETE_ITSELF or IN_IGNORED`. For vim 7.3, this will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Use fcntl to make the file descriptor non-blocking.